# finding the meaning of the obfuscated javascript

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

i saw this piece of code in an obfuscated javascript :

`if(1s Q.is.ep=='a')`

do you have any idea what this might mean? Im quite confused about the space..

thanks :)

Comment: where did you see the snippet? and source?

Comment: Context matters, a lot.

Comment: Can you provide more information? like more code? coz This question is also obfuscating in this form :).. (Not a Downvoter).

Comment: http://www.livesport.cz/x/js/core_1_943000000.js - search for '1s'

Comment: The entire code is run through a simple compression algorithm which is unpacked on the fly. None of it is directly valid JavaScript unless by coincidence.

Comment: @ondra That file is in minified so simply isn't readable and also has 1187 occurances of `1s` which `1s` exactly you want to mention?

Comment: for exmpale: if(1s sM==\'1u\')

Comment: I just wonder what kind of syntax construct is this : if(x y)  ?

Comment: As I said, it's not any kind of construct. It's not JavaScript at all.

Comment: it is not javascript? It can be read by browser so what kind of language is that?

Comment: Look, it's been **compressed**. You know, a bit like a zip file? When the code is *uncompressed*, then it becomes JavaScript that the browser understands.

Comment: My best guess is that 1s represents typeof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks like generated by Dean Edwards' [**packer**](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) (or another similar one). You could unpack it with [**this tool**](http://matthewfl.com/unPacker.html).

It's indeed JavaScript, however replaced keywords, method, variables with meaningless strings. The bottom half of the file you provided is actually a mapper between obscured and original.

And this, it the power of [**`eval`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) (and don't use `eval` if by all means you could do without it).